# Reflections in Dihedral Group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

In Dihedral Groups, what is the meaning of reflection ?

A line needs to be specified for a reflection to take place, but, if you specify only one line how will $D_n$ give all the symmetries for a n-gon? as there might be more than one axis of symmetry in a n-gon?

Comment: Each line of symmetry corresponds to a different reflection. The dihedral group of order $2n$ has $n$ reflections, one for each axis of symmetry.

Comment: I don't see what the difficulty is, but maybe the following can help. Consider $n=4$ so your $n$-gon is a square. If you specify the line to be either the line joining the centers of two opposite sides of the square or one of the diagonals, the reflection will preserve the square, i.e., it will map all points in the square to points in the square, and it will map all points outside the square to points outside the square.

Comment: @user44441  I thought it had one reflection and n rotations.Or are you saying that for those n lines a dihedral group can become a group of symmetry if one of the lines is chosen for reflection, which begs the question, how can only one type of reflection give all the symmetries of a n-gon .

Comment: Let me try to illustrate with an example: consider the dihedral group of order 6, the symmetries of an equilateral triangle, $\triangle ABC$. Let us denote the center of this triangle by $O$. Now we list the elements of $D_6 = \{1, r, r^2, s, sr, sr^2\}$, where $r$ denotes rotation counterclockwise by 120 degrees and $s$ denotes reflection in the line $OA$. Then $sr$ is a reflection in the line $OC$ and $sr^2$ is a reflection in the line $OB$ (assuming $A,B,C$ are listed counter-clockwise). Thus, any dihedral group of order $2n$ has $n$ rotations (including the identity) and $n$ reflections.

Comment: Also to answer your question: yes, all you need to generate the dihedral group is one rotation (of order $n$) and one reflection, and this can be any of the $n$ reflections. You always end up with the same group up to isomorphism. Maybe your confusion is from the fact that given one reflection, you can get all the others by simply "multiplying" this reflection with powers of a given (primitive) rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can feel you... it's very frustrating that even this very simple but important question is somehow never explained explicitly everywhere!

The reflection could be defined completely and without any confusing, by the line of symmetry through vertex 1, and the center of the object.

It seems confusing as there are many lines of symmetry, but how could just one line of symmetry be enough to represent it all? You could see from the following picture, that no matter which line of symmetry we chose, the reflection would always turn the order of vertices from 1 to 4 clockwise to counter clockwise and vice versa.

[image]

Even though each line of symmetry above moves vertex 2 to a different position, it doesn't matter which line of symmetry we choose, we could always get the other configurations by simply rotating the n-polygon. As such, after a reflection there could be only two possibilities of the location of vertex 2, that is clockwise after vertex 1, or before vertex 1. Thus in all, for an n-polygon, there are $n$ configurations of rotations, and only $2$ configuration of reflections, make it all in total $2n$ configurations of symmetry.

It could also be understood that symmetries are rigid motions, so once the position of the ordered pair of vertices 1 and 2 are fixed, the action of the symmetry on all remaining vertices is completely determined. In the above picture, our convention chooses to always use line of symmetry through vertices 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

There are many comments and answers and I will add a hint for a geometric approach. Draw a few regular polygons, for example with $n=3,4,5,6,7$ and $8$ vertices.

The symmetry group consists of $n$ rotations and $n$ reflections:

- If $n$ is even, a half of the symmetry axes pass through two opposite vertices, the other half through the midpoint of opposite sides.
- If $n$ is odd, all axes pass through a vertex and the midpoint of the opposite side

When you have one axis of symmetry, you get the other by rotating this axis with a certain angle. This can be done with $e^{i\phi}$ for certain angles $\phi$, when you see the problem in the complex plane.

For example when $n=3$, you have to rotate with angle $120^{\circ}=\frac{360^{\circ}}{3}\equiv\frac{2\pi}{3}$. You get all symmetries by repeatedly rotation with this specified angle.

The representation of $D_{2n}$ is $\langle r,s|r^n=s^2=\mathrm{id},srs=r^{-1}\rangle$, the reflections are $s,sr,sr^2,\ldots,sr^{n-1}$. In the complex plane, $r$ can be viewed as $e^{2\pi i/n}$, thus you need $e^{2\pi i k/n}$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, where you $k=0$ actually don't need.

Comment: I think we read composition of symmetries left to right. 
Using this notation we get $s,rs,rs,\ldots,r^{n-1}s$.

Comment: That's not the important thing, since $sr^k =r^{-k}s=r^{n-k}s$.